# Python ldif injection and csv reading script

Tags: python, csv

Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?
I'm writing a python shell script that takes an ldif file and a csv file and then appends the contents in the csv file to the end of each record in the ldif.  Something like:

Sample CSV:

```
    "KEY","VALUE"
    "abc","def"
    "foo","bar"
    "qwop","flop"
```

Sample .ldif:

```
    dn: Aziz
    cn: Aziz_09

    dn: Carl
    cn: Carl_04
```

After python myscript.py "sample.ldif" "sample.csv"

```
    dn: Aziz
    cn: Aziz_09
    KEY: VALUE
    abc: def
    foo: bar
    qwop: flop

    dn: Carl
    cn: Carl_04
    KEY: VALUE
    abc: def
    foo: bar
    qwop: flop
```

So far my code compiles however it doesn't modify the file correctly.  I'm creating an object that takes a csv file path name string on creation and then stores the keys into a list field and stores the values into a list field.  I then open the ldif file, parse for the escape characters between records and insert the list fields (KEY and VALUE) at the end of each record:

```
    import sys, csv

    #  Make new object that can open a csv and set csv data in its arrays
    class Container(object):
      def __init__(self, filename=None, keys=None, values=None):
        self.filename = filename
        self.keys = []
        self.values = []

      #  Opens self.filename and puts 0th and 1st rows into keys and values respectively  
      def csv_to_list():
        with open(self.filename, 'rb') as f:
          reader = csv.reader(f)
          for row in reader:
            self.keys = row[0]
            self.values = row[1]

    haruhi = Container("./content/test_pairs.txt")
    haruhi.csv_to_list

    # open first argument of the command line call to ldif_record_a.py for read/writing
    with open(sys.argv[1],'r+') as f1:
      lines=[x.strip() for x in f1]  # Create list with each line as an element
      f1.truncate(0)
      f1.seek(0)
      count = 0
      for x in lines:
         if x:
           f1.write(x+'\n')
         else:
           f1.write("{0}: {1}\n\n".format(haruhi.keys[count] , haruhi.values[count]))
           count = count + 1
      f1.write("{0}: {1}\n\n".format(haruhi.keys[count] , haruhi.values[count]))
```

I am new to Python!  Any help, advice and/or resource direction would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you SO

Comment: What python version do you use ?

Comment: Instead of `self.keys = row[0]` I guess you want to say `self.keys.append(row[0])` ?

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry I'm using 2.7

Comment: @Shuang I'm not sure, could you elaborate?

Comment: In 2.7 better use string="{}" string.format()

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry: That's what they're doing, string format-wise.

Comment: @FreddieJuliusMonkeyking: Is `./content/test_pairs.txt` the `sample.csv` file? If not, what is it?

Comment: @FreddieJuliusMonkeyking: Do you really want the `KEY: VALUE` header row from the csv file appended to each ldif record?

Comment: @martineau  Ya test_pairs.txt is the test csv I am using, and yes KEY: VALUE should be appended.  I'm actually tackling this problem in a different way now by storing the data of the csv and the ldif into two separate dictionaries.  I'm going to have two modes in my program.  Update mode and Concat mode.  In update mode I'll update the ldif values of corresponding keys with the csv values.  In concate mode I'll be doing the original concatenation of the Key: Value pairs to the end of each ldif record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I adhoc'd this, so it needs work, but here goes:

```
import csv
import re

csv_data = list(csv.reader(open('/home/jon/tmp/data.csv'))) # (1)
csv_text = '\n' + '\n'.join('{0} : {1}'.format(*row) for row in csv_data) # (2)

with open('/home/jon/tmp/other.ldif') as f:
    contents = f.read() # (3)
    print re.sub(r'(\n\n)|(\n$)', csv_text + '\n\n', contents) # (4)
```

- (1) Read the CSV file into a list of lists

  csv_data == [['KEY', 'VALUE'], ['abc', 'def'], ['foo', 'bar'], ['qwop', 'flop']]
- (2) Create a text representation to be append to each ldif

  KEY : VALUE
  abc : def
  foo : bar
  qwop : flop
- (3) Open and read the entire contents into memory (not very efficient mind you)
- (4) Use a regular expression to find the "next bit" after the ldif and put in text

**Prints:**

```
dn: Aziz
cn: Aziz_09
KEY : VALUE
abc : def
foo : bar
qwop : flop

dn: Carl
cn: Carl_04
KEY : VALUE
abc : def
foo : bar
qwop : flop
```

You'll need to adjust it to write data back out or whatever you want..., but is a possible starting point - but strongly recommend you use it a base to work through accompanied by the Python manual. Feel free to ask for any clarification.